# Sending Multicast Packets does just work over P2P

Tags: p2p, multicast

I am stucked within a weired problem. I have two little programs (written in C, using Win API), the one sends a multicast package, the other one receives it. Well, I tried it between two notebooks, the one running win7, the other win8, and it works as expected while running a P2P connection between them (=without switch, just the patch cable plugged into both hosts).
But when I try to connect a switch between both hosts it does not work. I also tested a hub, but that dows not work either. I tested it over wifi, but it still does not work.

The Multicast Packet works just over P2P. And THAT seems to be weired.

Firewall is off, also any other security software. Ping works in any configuration as expected.

Any tip would be highly appreciated :-)

Dirk

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem for myself - the notebook I tried to send the packets has virtualbox installed. After Disabling the virtualbox service the connection worked successfully. I still don't know exactly the reason, but this workaround helped for me.